# total variation and monotonicy

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation

I am stuck with this problem : I have a finite variation function $f$ and I have proved that the total variation on the interval $[0,t]$, denoted with $S_t^f$ for $t\in[0,T]$, is increasing. How can I prove that the function $S_t^f+f(t)$ is increasing too ?

Thank you very much for any help you can provide :)

Comment: Sorry...total variation and monotonicity :)

Answer (score 2):

Well you are not getting much help here and perhaps the homework deadline is looming--so here is a push.

The function $f:[0,T]\to \mathbb{R}$   has bounded variation there. You already have seen, for any $0\leq a<b\leq T$, that $$V(f,[a,b]) + f(b)-f(a)\geq 0$$ is trivial.

What you need to show now is that $$V(f,[0,a]) + V(f,[a,b])= V(f,[0,b]).$$
As is often the case, to show equality you show inequality--two of them.  That is you have two inequalities to establish:
$$V(f,[0,a]) + V(f,[a,b]) \leq V(f,[0,b])$$ and
$$V(f,[0,a]) + V(f,[a,b]) \geq V(f,[0,b]).$$
One is easy and the other will require you to get your hands dirty with partitions and the like.  (Think of a partition of $[0,b]$ and what would happen if you add "$a$" to it.)

[Note that I am delaying the notation $S^f_t=V(f,[0,t])$ for later since it is not very intuitive and can easily mislead you.]

---

Alternatively, you can just search around for textbooks that give a proof of Jordan's theorem for BV functions, that characterizes them as differences of monotone functions (which is what you are doing here).  Some use exactly this method; Royden's *Real Analysis* uses the clever idea of defining two half-variations (a positive variation and a negative variation) that ends up in the same place.  My favorite presentation of this topic is in Zygmund and Wheeden, *Measure and Integral*.  The techniques needed to solve this problem are, while elementary, absolutely essential to an ability to understand and do real analysis.  It is not a waste of time to linger on this problem until it is all completely transparent to you.

Comment: Hmmm? Downvote wars?  Borderline impolite perhaps.

Answer (score -1):

For any fixed partition $a=x_0\leq\dots\leq x_n =b$ we have
$$
  S^f(b) -S^f(a) + f(b) - f(a) \geq \sum_{i = 0}^{n-1} |f(x_{i+1}) - f(x_i)| + \sum_{i = 0}^{n-1} (f(x_{i+1}) - f(x_i)) \geq 0
$$
since $y + |y| \geq 0$ for all $y$. Hence, when you take $\sup$ over partitions, the inequality still holds.

Comment: I am sorry, but I can´t understand the first inequality...could you please give me some more details ? Can you be more explicit ?

Comment: @FredG. what's the definition of total variation you use?

Comment: I use the following : for every partition $\Delta=(0=t_0<t_1< \dots < t_n=t)$ of the interval $[0,t]$ I can consider the value $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} |f(t_{i+1}-f(t_i}|$. The total variation is the $\sup$ of this quantity over all partitions. Have I made myself clear ?

Comment: @FredG. yes, that's why difference in total variation is greater or equal to the first sum in my inequality, and difference in function itself always equals the second sum (telescopic series).

Comment: ok, but I still do not get why the difference in total variation is greater or equal to the first sum. I mean, you're saying that the sup over $[0,b]$ is greater or equal the sup over $[0,a]$ + the sup over $[a,b]$. Are you sure ?

Comment: I am a bit confused, sorry :)

Comment: Seems to me that Mr Iyla has proved only that $V(f,[a,b]) + f(b)-f(a)\geq 0$ but what Mr G. wants is that $V(f,[a,b])=S^f(b)-S^f(a)$.

Comment: Also Mr Ilya, even that proof is unnecessary.  Take the simplest of all partitions of $[a,b]$, namely $a=x_0<x_1=b$ and of course $$V(f,[a,b]) + f(b)-f(a) \geq |f(x_1)-f(x_0)| + f(x_1) -f(x_0) \geq 0.$$